# Global Transforms besides the DFT?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, transform

This is a simple question. Fourier analysis gives us the DFT, which is known as a global transform of a signal. In contrast, the Discrete Wavelet Transform (DWT) has a plethora of wavelets, all of which fall under the umbrella of local transforms.

I wonder, might there be other global transforms besides projection onto a family of orthogonal complex exponentials as with the DFT?

(I am aware of the DST and DCT, however I am looking for applicable non-sinusoidal bases).

Thanks!

Comment: The [Hadamard transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform) is an example. It uses [Walsh functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_function) as its basis.

Comment: For the sake of opening up discussion on this, can you define what "global" and "local" mean in the context of a transform?

Comment: @BruceZenone Global in this context would mean a transformation that acts on the entire length of the signal. In other words, the entire signal is projected upon a set of bases functions. (DFT). In contrast, local transformations would be where only parts of the signal are projected upon basis functions. (DWT).